# Problem with MP4/H264 metadata crop values

Tags: vlc, video-player, mp4, metadata, mpv-media-player

I have Ubuntu 20.04 Mate, VLC 3.0.9.2, MPV 0.32.0, MPlayer 1.3.0, AVIdemux 2.7.6.

I have a video file (H264/AAC/MP4) in 16:9 aspect (1024x576p) where the video was accidentaly horizontaly squeezed to 4:3 and letterboxed with black bars at the right and left sides to fill the full 16:9 frame size. I didn't want to re-encode it, so I tried to use MP4 metadata to correct the squeezing and remove the black bars. To do so, I used these two `ffmpeg` commands:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -aspect 235:100 -c copy outputfile.mp4
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -bsf:v h264_metadata=crop_left=128:crop_right=128:crop_top:0:crop_bottom=0 -codec copy outputfile.mp4
```

I opened the resulting file with VLC 3.0.9.2, MPV 0.32.0, MPlayer 1.3.0, and AVIdemux 2.7.6 and this was the result:

[image: screenshot comparison of playback results]

- Only MPlayer showed the new aspect ratio and cropped both sides correctly.
- AVIdemux ignored the new aspect ratio but cropped both sides correctly.
- MPV showed the new aspect ratio but left the left side uncropped, only the right side was cropped correctly.
- VLC showed the new aspect ratio but left the left side uncropped, the right side was cropped but not correctly (it seems that the left value was added to the right value).

I filed this issue on [the VLC](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/28279) and [the MPV](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/11833) bug lists. But as always when I do so the developers answer that I have an outdated version of their software (which is a general problem with Ubuntu repositories) and that I didn't include all the necessary information. Maybe someone else who is more qualified than me can file a "valid" issue.

Or maybe someone knows how to bypass this issue without involving the developers (maybe it's not even a bug, but I rather doubt that)

Comment: Have you found the solution yet? I'm having the same type of problem

Comment: @kodsu - It's on the VLC bug list (https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/28279), but I fear it will take years until it gets fixed.

Comment: I actually tried to watch the video with a chromium based browser (MS Edge) with a simple <video /> tag and the cropping worked like a charm. So yes, VLC (and others) don't honor the h264_metadata (or partially). With Safari it won't work either (tried on my iPhone). So basically it depends on the player, some players will honor the h264_metadata some won't.